# How do i get my my characters to start jumping using pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying out a jumping code in my program but the characters aren't jumping. (Character 1s controls are 'a' 'd' and character 2s controls are 'left arrow' 'right arrow'. How do i get the character 1 to jump with w and character 2 to jump with up arrow. I'm not sure whats wrong with the code as this is my first time implementing a jumping mechanic.

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((700, 480))
pygame.display.set_caption("First project")
run = True
red = (255, 0, 0)
green = (0, 255, 0)


def drawbg():
    pygame.display.update()
    win.fill((255, 255, 255))


class person(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.vel = 5
        self.IsJump = False
        self.jumpCount = 10


man = person(100, 400, 50, 60)
man2 = person(500, 400, 50, 60)

while run:
    pygame.time.delay(25)


    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and man2.x > man2.vel:
        man2.x -= man2.vel

    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and man2.x < 700 - man2.width - man2.vel:
        man2.x += man2.vel

    if keys[pygame.K_a] and man.x > man.vel:
        man.x -= man.vel

    if keys[pygame.K_d] and man.x < 700 - man.width - man.vel:
        man.x += man.vel

    if not man.IsJump and keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
        man.IsJump = True
        man.JumpCount = 10

    if man.IsJump:
        if man.JumpCount >= -10:
            neg = 1
            if man.JumpCount < 0:
                neg = -1
            man.y -= (man.JumpCount ** 2) / 2 * neg
            man.JumpCount -= 1
        else:
            man.IsJump = False
            man.JumpCount = 10

    pygame.draw.rect(win, red, (man.x, man.y, man.width, man.height))
    pygame.draw.rect(win, green, (man2.x, man2.y, man2.width, man2.height))
    drawbg()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Character 1 (`man`) jumps with `pygame.K_SPACE`, so change it to `pygame.K_w`?

Answer (score 1):

Move the code which handles the jump, to an `update` method of the class `person`:

```py
class person(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.vel = 5
        self.IsJump = False
        self.jumpCount = 10

    def update(self): 
        if self.IsJump:
            if self.JumpCount >= -10:
                neg = 1 if self.JumpCount >= 0  else -1
                self.y -= (self.JumpCount ** 2) / 2 * neg
                self.JumpCount -= 1
            else:
                self.IsJump = False
                self.JumpCount = 10
```

Activate jumping of player 1 (`man`) on <kbd>k</kbd> and jumping of player 2 (`man2`) on <kbd>UP</kbd>.
Call the `update` method for the objects `man` and `man2` after the event handling:

```py
while run:
    pygame.time.delay(25)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and man2.x > man2.vel:
        man2.x -= man2.vel
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and man2.x < 700 - man2.width - man2.vel:
        man2.x += man2.vel

    if keys[pygame.K_a] and man.x > man.vel:
        man.x -= man.vel
    if keys[pygame.K_d] and man.x < 700 - man.width - man.vel:
        man.x += man.vel

    if not man.IsJump and keys[pygame.K_w]:
        man.IsJump = True
        man.JumpCount = 10
    if not man2.IsJump and keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        man2.IsJump = True
        man2.JumpCount = 10

    man.update()
    man2.update()

    pygame.draw.rect(win, red, (man.x, man.y, man.width, man.height))
    pygame.draw.rect(win, green, (man2.x, man2.y, man2.width, man2.height))
    drawbg()

pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you didn't write codes to react with keyboard input w (`pygame.K_w`) and up (`pygame.K_UP`) at first. However, in your code that you uploaded, player1 (`man`) already can jump with space bar (`K_SPACE`) properly. you can copy that part, and just change some variables for `man2`.